# Setting CaseComment CreatorName (audit field)

Tags: apex

I want to copy all case comment into newly created case with the same details like body,creator name etc.

But what I am thinking Creator Name is not writeable so creator name will be running user name for each and every comments added.

Is there any way to get the same creator name when inserting case comments into other case.

Answer (score 2):

You can contact support to enable the ability to insert any value you like into audit fields. See the entry on [System Fields](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm). Some standard objects and all custom objects are supported.

Comment: Hi, I have been heard salesforce make field audit for some time not permanently. Because when they enables system field it enables to all salesforce object which are allowed. M I correct ? so in this case apex trigger will require a these field permanently which does not possible.

Comment: I think if you make a strong case about needing to control these fields, they would allow it, but they strongly advise against it.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right, but I don't think they would allow for a single object. I will talk.